# Asp.Net Mvc 4 jQuery Ajax Insert Data

Tags: jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

I'm new to Asp.Net Mvc. I'm trying to achieve insert data to database with jQuery ajax. It is inserting data but also it provides error:

> alert('Ajax call error').

Code below:

JS:

```
function SaveComment() {
    var author = $("#author").val();
    var comment = $("#comment").val();
    var articleId = $("#HdnArticleId").val();
    $("#commentgif").show();
    $("#btn").attr("disabled", "true");

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Home/SaveComment",
        data: "{author:'" + author + "', comment:'" + comment + "', articleId:'" + articleId + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: Success,
        error: function (msg) {
            $("#commentgif").hide();
            alert("Ajax call error!");
            $("#btn").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    });
}
```

C#:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveComment(string author, string comment, int articleId)
{
    CommentBLL CommBLL = new CommentBLL();
    Comment NewComment = new Comment();
    NewComment.ArticleId = articleId;
    NewComment.Content = comment;
    NewComment.IsActive = false;
    NewComment.Name = author;
    NewComment.Date = DateTime.Now;
    CommBLL.Save(NewComment);
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Because `success:Success` is not valid in this case, you need to provide `success` callback to it!

Answer (score 0):

Try to receive your parameters in SaveComment method as string and convert *articleId* then.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the ActionResult to JsonResult on your action, because in your ajax call, you're expecting the JSON data:

```
dataType: "json",
```